# JavaScript/PHP string equality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm running an Ajax call which has a success function which takes in a variable returned from the PHP page like so.

Ajax:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loginrequest.php",
      data: 'username=' + username + '&password=' +pass,
    success: function(html){
        console.log(html); // Returns login
        console.log(typeof html); // Returns string
        console.log(html === "login"); // Returns false

        if(html === 'login'){
            window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }
        else if(html === 'false'){
            alert("login failed");
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
if($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $myusername;
    $return = "login";
    echo json_encode($return);
}
else {
    $return = "false";
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to implement a simple login page and then redirect the user or display an alert depending on the outcome of the number of rows returned from my database query.

What I don't understand is this:

```
console.log(html); // Returns "login"
console.log(typeof html); // Returns string
console.log(html === "login"); // Returns false
```

I tried echo-ing without `json_encode()` and it still would give me the same results. I was using `==`, but then I read that it's safer to use `===`, so I switched to that, but it still won't return true.

Comment: To fix the immediate issue, try `console.log(html.trim() === "login");`. `trim()` removes the additional whitespace which can be appended to the response when dealing with plain text. As an improvement, return JSON instead to avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: `json_encode` adds `"` to the string, so you actually have `"login"` with the quotes. Take a look: [https://eval.in/600312](https://eval.in/600312)

Comment: A quick `var_dump` of the generated 'json' would've easily showed the problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending JSON, which means that you're sending the literal bytes:

```
"login"
"false"
```

Note the quotes in there. Your JavaScript code either needs to decode the JSON, or compare the raw JSON itself:

```
 result = JSON.parse(html)
 if (result == "login")
```

or

```
 if (html == '"login"')   // Note the quotes
```

A simple `console.log(html)` would have shown you what you're dealing with.

Comment: From the question, the op actually did run `console.log(html); // returns "login"`, but they probably thought it was how the console displays strings... xD

Comment: json is a string. plain and simple. that's the whole point of it. encoding arbitrary JS data structures/types into a simple string for transport. raw json received via http will always be a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `json_encode` on the PHP side then you should use:

`jQuery.parseJSON` on the JavaScript side -

```
html = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
```